# Suspicious startup program entries on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1

I just viewed my "Software Environment->Start-up Programs" in the System Information app on Windows 8.1 and found a couple of entries that look a bit odd (see the top 2 entries on the image).

There are no programs associated with these entries, the command name is Chinese, Japanese or something similar and they are owned by the legitimate users "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" and ".DEFAULT"

Are these legitimate programs? Can anyone throw any light on what these might be?

Thanks.

[Screenshot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gq0Zf.jpg)

Comment: That sure looks like obfuscation to me. Can you copy and paste the command text into Google Translate and see if you can glean any more info off of it?

Comment: “Are these legitimate programs?” - I can’t read Chinese, if you did not install the software, then it’s not legitimate

Comment: OK, It's Chinese.  The first one says "Ruǎn Í" and the second one says "jē pào Í".  Meaningless to me.  Additionally, there is nothing suspicious in the Start-up section of the Task Manager.

Comment: Ramhound, If I knew that I installed these then I wouldn't be asking here.  Windows does tend to add components that the average user has no knowledge about and, in fact, doesn't care about, as long as the system works.  In this case, the NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM user is more powerful that an Administrator and this is a bit worrying.  There is nothing that I have found anywhere else on this box that would lead me to believe that they were installed by any user-accessible method.  Also, my virus scanner reports nothing unusual.

Comment: @AuricMists have you check this out with SysInternals AutoRuns utility? It may give you more info on what is running on start up and provide some insight here.

Comment: @JG7, Nothing unusual reported by SysInternals.  I also quickly checked the registry manually for oddities but didn't get very far, although I did spot a Logitech program spawning from the NT AUTHORITY user so will investigate that further in the morning.  Thanks for your help.